# mount error(6): No such device or address when sharing windows folder to ubuntu

Tags: mount, smb

I have a windows shared folder named `\\mymachine\sf` and I want to map it as a ubuntu device. I use smbmount command as below:

```
smbmount //mymachine/sf /mnt/sf -o <username>
```

The output is like

```
retrying with upper case share name
mount error(6): No such device or address
Refer to the mount.cifs(8) manual page (e.g. man mount.cifs)
```

I'm sure the device exists and `mymachine` is ping'ed through.

Any idea?

Answer (score 16):

Double check that the share exists and is the name you expect with:

```
smbclient -L //mymachine -U <username>
```

Answer (score 2):

Also double check that the directory your share points to (as mentioned in smb.conf) actually exists on the server/host. This is one situation where you will receive that error, despite `smbclient -L //hostname` giving reasonable output.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the directory the samba share points to exists on the server side as well (might have been deleted or mount might have failed at boot). `smbclient -L //mymachine -U <username>` lists shares as available even though they're not available!